# How to repeat codes changing the variables in a sequence in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, r-raster

This is the code I want to repeat

```
A_1981 <- Base[1:12]]
B <- sum(A_1981)
MFI_1981 <- sum(A_1981^2)/B
```

Base is a Raster brick

A_1981 is for a year

MFI_1981 is the final result

So i have to continue with the next year

```
A_1982 <- Base[13:24]]
B <- sum(A_1982)
MFI_1982 <- sum(A_1982^2)/B
```

To repeat the same code I think in replace values only in the names:

```
a <- seq(1,421,by=12)
b <- seq(12,432,by=12)
c <- seq(1981,2016, by=1)
```

And do it in sequence for the next third year, would be something like this

```
A_a[3] <- Base[[b[3]:c[3]]
B <- sum(A_a[3])
MFI_a[3] <- sum(A_[3]^2)/B
```

Have to be some way with for or make a function. But have no idea where to start.

Comment: Do you need to create these objects in the global env?

Comment: I think you got your a, b, and c mixed up in that last chunk of code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this

Example data (48 layers, i.e, 4 "years")

```
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")
Base <- stack(rep(f, 4*4))
```

Approach 1

```
f <- function(year) {
    start <- (year-1981) * 12 + 1
    A <- Base[[start:(start+11)]]
    sum(A^2)/sum(A)
}

mfi <- lapply(1981:1984, f)
MFI <- stack(mfi)
```

Approach 2

```
for (year in 1981:1984) {
    start <- (year-1981) * 12 + 1
    A <- Base[[start:(start+11)]]
    mfi <- sum(A^2)/sum(A)
    writeRaster(mfi, paste0(year, ".tif"))
}

s <- stack(paste0(1981:1984, ".tif"))
```

Approach 3, with `mapply` as in Rui Barradas' answer, but fixed for when `Base` is a `RasterBrick` (and also including the last year)

```
n <- nlayers(Base)
a <- seq(1, n, by = 12)
mfi <- mapply(function(i, j) sum(Base[[i:j]]^2)/sum(Base[[i:j]]), a, a+11)
s <- stack(mfi)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following does what you want using `mapply` and creates only one object in the `.GlobalEnv`, which I named `MFI`.

I start by creating a vector `Base`, since you have not posted a dataset example.

```
set.seed(2469)    # Make the results reproducible

n <- 432
Base <- sample(100, n, TRUE)

step <- 12
b <- seq(1 + step, n, by = step)
a <- seq(1, n - step, by = step)

MFI <- mapply(function(i, j) sum(Base[i:j]^2)/sum(Base[i:j]), a, b)


head(MFI)
#[1] 63.66472 70.54014 67.60567 53.15550 58.71111 65.37008
```

Another way would be to use `Map`, like @Parfait suggests in his comment.

```
obj <- Map(function(i, j) sum(Base[i:j]^2)/sum(Base[i:j]), a, b)
names(obj) <- paste("MFI", 1980 + seq_along(obj), sep = "_")

obj$MFI_1981
#[1] 63.66472
```

Note that `length(obj)` is `35` and therefore the last `obj` is `obj$MFI_2015` and not `MFI_2016` like is said in the question. This can be easily solved by making `n <- 444` right at the beginning of the code.

Comment: Or use the simplified wrapper to `mapply`, `Map`, and return a list of elements (not vector) and even name items according to OP's needs: *MFI_1981*, *MFI_1982*, ... for *obj$MFI_1981*, *obj$MFI_1982* referencing.